# Определить чем сжата строка

Tags: сжатие

подскажите чем сжата строка? если это возможно определить )

Хранится просто в ini файле в нем по всей видимости конфигурация приложения

https://pastebin.com/Fg7JRmYj

И если возможно получить текст то каким методом?

Comment: Там строка в base64, а внутри зашифровано и я не знаю чем. Нужно смотреть кем файл был создан и как шифруется. Я как-то взламывал файл сохранения одной кривой игрушки на Unity и ключ для шифрования был зашит в ее коде (не будь она кривой и не потеряв весь мой прогресс после внезапного падения, я бы не стал ее ломать :D): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/hacking__game__Rezrog (в файле `progress.json` находится зашифрованная строка, сохраненная в base64, а в `main.py` скрипт с инструкцией взлома и с функциями (де)шифрования)

Comment: Pearl Abyss игра black desert конфиг лаунчера

Comment: но если обратите внимание то там есть пробелы